# SQL script to pull in latest inventory data from table

Tags: sql, duplicates, amazon-selling-partner-api

My data in the table `sp_restock_inventory_v2_view` is pulled in several times a day. This makes it so multiple records for each ASIN are pulled in daily. Sometimes they are duplicates, but sometimes stock changes and the records are not the same. How do I write something that only queries the latest stock for each ASIN?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM sp-api-connector.CollectorMount.sp_restock_inventory_v2_view AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT product_name, MAX(ob_date) AS max_ob_date
    FROM sp-api-connector.CollectorMount.sp_restock_inventory_v2_view
    GROUP BY product_name
) AS t2 ON t1.product_name = t2.product_name AND t1.ob_date = t2.max_ob_date;
```

and some similar scripts, but none really work the way I want.

data structure looks like this:

| asin | available | product_name | ob_date | merchant_sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B08W22TLAA | 100 | product1 | 2023-04-23 | 135876 |
| B08W22TLAA | 89 | product1 | 2023-04-23 | 135876 |
| B08W22TLAC | 37 | product2 | 2023-04-23 | 135875 |
| B08W22TLAC | 33 | product2 | 2023-04-23 | 135875 |

Comment: [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: is there any primary key?  what is structure of table?

Comment: `GROUP BY asin` ...?

Comment: added data structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT v.*, ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY product_name ORDER BY ob_date DESC) as RN
    FROM sp-api-connector.CollectorMount.sp_restock_inventory_v2_view v
) sub
WHERE sub.RN = 1
```

Note, you should never use * -- list out only the columns you need.  I used * because I don't know the column names you need.